# Site falls over on loss of single "key" memcached instance in distributed cluster

Tags: 7, caching

I have a Drupal 7 site sitting behind HAProxy that is load balancing across 4 web servers.

Each of these web servers is also running a memcached instance. All the Drupal applications have been identically configured to distribute their cache across all these memcached instances using consistent hashing.

I'm seeing a problem when testing failover; Basically one of the memcached instances seems to be randomly designated as being special, stopping this memcached instance will take the site off line.

Any of the other three non-key instances can be stopped and the site will continue to run; however if the key memcached is stopped the site performance across all web servers suddenly becomes terrible; greater than 10sec for a single authenticated page response. Because the health check configuration in HAProxy then times out the entire site is then taken offline until the key memcached instance is restored.

Some other observations:

- Stopping and then starting all the drupal instances will change which instance is the key memcached; it is not one particular server.
- We have observed this behaviour with both the [memcache](https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache) and [memcache-storage](https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache_storage) modules in Drupal.
- It remains the same whether I have locking (and sessions in the case of memcache-storage) in memcached or not.

Our config is roughly as below (`MEMCACHED_HOSTS` is a comma delimited environment variable of `<hostname>:<port>`:

```
/**
 * Memcached setup for Drupal
 */
$conf['memcache_servers'] = array();
foreach(explode(',',getenv('MEMCACHED_HOSTS')) as $mc_host) {
  $conf['memcache_servers'][$mc_host] = 'default';
}

$conf['memcache_extension'] = 'Memcached';

$conf['cache_backends'] = array(
  'sites/all/modules/contrib/memcache/memcache.inc',
  'sites/all/modules/contrib/cache_consistent/cache_consistent.inc',
);

// Set default cache backend to use Cache Consistent.
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'ConsistentCache';

$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_update'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';

// Set Cache Consistent's default backend to memcache.
$conf['consistent_cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';

// Don't skip cache_set() operations during transactions.
// When using the isolation level REPEATABLE-READ, safe mode should be set to
// TRUE. When using READ-COMMITTED, it should be FALSE.
// What safe mode does, is that it discards cache writes during transactions, to
// avoid storing stale data into the cache. This is due to transaction snapshots
// and MVCC.
$conf['consistent_cache_default_safe'] = FALSE;

// Set cache consistent's buffer mechanism to ConsistentCacheBuffer. (default)
// There's currently only one buffer mechanism bundled with Cache Consistent.
$conf['consistent_cache_buffer_mechanism'] = 'ConsistentCacheBuffer';

// Don't do strict expire checking on each item for all bins. (default)
$conf['consistent_cache_default_strict'] = FALSE;

// Strict expire checking on each item for cache_bootstrap.
$conf['consistent_cache_strict_cache_bootstrap'] = TRUE;

$conf['memcache_options'] = array(
  Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION => FALSE,
  Memcached::OPT_DISTRIBUTION => Memcached::DISTRIBUTION_CONSISTENT,
  Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL => TRUE,
  Memcached::OPT_TCP_NODELAY => TRUE,
);

$conf['page_cache_without_database'] = TRUE;
$conf['page_cache_invoke_hooks'] = FALSE;

/**
 * Moving the locking machanism to memcache to avoid DB cluster issues
 */
$conf['memcache_stampede_protection'] = TRUE;
$conf['lock_inc'] = 'sites/all/modules/contrib/memcache/memcache-lock.inc';
```

I am going to test to see whether this is a memcached vs memcache PCEL issue next and will update this if anything changes, but at this point any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update 1**
I've tried now with both memcached and memcache PCEL extensions, the issue occurs with both.

Also, I should confirm that I am seeing all memcached instances being used, so it's not a case of just a single instance being used.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Notice that you are stating facts without asking any explicit question. What exactly don't you understand? In what exactly do you need help (e.g. changing the settings)? Keep in mind that we cannot debug a site to which we don't have access, so we cannot tell you "try this" or give suggestions/hints, since that is not the purpose of this site. Also, it is hard to give answers for a complex configuration like that, for which very few is being described.